# Unwanted space between two layouts in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, space

[image]

Hi

I have designed a layout, i have attached a screen shot of it. I was getting an unwanted space between linear layout(tabsFragmentll) and grid view linear layout, so to remove the space i added a tag in linear layout grid view as android:layout_marginTop= "-10dp".
After adding the tag, it removed the space between the linear layout(tabsFragmentll) and grid view linear layout, but at the bottom of the screen i am getting an unwanted space which is shown at the bottom of the screen. 
I am trying hard to remove the unwanted spaces, but am not able to do so. Please look in to it and give me your suggestions. 
The following is my layout design code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/slide_show_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/slide_show_fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabsFragmentll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.beverly.fragments.TabsButtonFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.15"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/center_pane_rl"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/center_pane_frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/places_list_view_progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_fragment_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRowBtns"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/checkinframe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/checkInIB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/checkin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkInTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/checkin"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cameraframe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cameraIB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/camera" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cameraTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/camera"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/photosframe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/photosIB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/photos" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/photosTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/photos"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/termsframe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/termsIB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/terms" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/termsTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/terms"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: use hierarchyviewer to see the exact margins applied to each layout. it will help you understand where the gap comes from